# Chloride Process TiO2 recovery

Tags: reaction-control, chemical-engineering

In the chloride process (the process used to create titanium oxide from titanium ore), how is TiO2 collected? What prevents the TiO2 from building up on the walls of the reactor chamber?

It's my assumption that the solid titania produced in a TiCl4+O2 reaction (assuming that the TiCl4 and O2 are all gases at 200 C) would plate out on the walls of the reactor chamber (since it is the one solid in the reaction). When manufacturing titania, how do manufacturers prevent the titania from plating out on the walls? Also, how would they collect it?

Comment: Can yoe be a bit more specific about where you see the problem, because at the moment this looks like a homework question.

Comment: @Karl Sure thing, it's my assumption that the solid titania produced in a TiCl4+O2 reaction (assuming that the TiCl4 and O2 are all gases at 200 C) would plate out on the walls of the reactor chamber (since it is the one solid in the reaction). When manufacturing titania, how do manufacturers prevent the titania from plating out on the walls? Also, how would they collect it?

Comment: Its a fine powder with very high melting point. I dont see it sticking to the wall, and would collect it with a cyclone, like those filterless vacuum cleaners, the brand name of which I will not mention. ;)